# Problema ao alterar entidade com E.F e Dapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, dapper

Tenho uma consulta Dapper, onde faço a busca de uma entidade:

```
var fatura = ObterPorClientedEDataVencimento(cobranca.ClienteId, cobranca.DataCobranca);
```

O Método e as propriedades da minha entidade estão neste `Gist`, coloquei lá apenas para a pergunta não ficar muito extensa.
https://gist.github.com/Renancp01/66e5d10a66c97b1bf791bae044bffdab

Que traz os dados normalmente. Porém, quando tento alterar esta entidade, tenho o erro:

> Attaching an entity of type 'PagueLa.Gateway.Domain.Entities.Fatura'
>   failed because another entity of the same type already has the same
>   primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or
>   setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any
>   entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because
>   some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key
>   values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state
>   to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to
>   'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.",
>       "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException

Pelo que entendi do erro, o E.F não "detectou" que estou tentando fazer uma alteração, mesmo setando o *Status* da entidade como `Modified`, e tenta adiciona-la novamente, mas o Id já é existente no banco. Segue meu método abaixo para uma melhor compreensão do problema:

```
cobranca.FaturaId = fatura.FaturaId;
fatura.Valor += cobranca.Valor;
_cobrancaRepository.Atualizar(cobranca);
Db.Entry(fatura).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Fiz um teste pegando o `ID` da fatura, da consulta feita com Dapper e fiz um ObterPorId com o E.F e o erro não acontece.

```
//Isso Funciona
var fatura = ObterPorClientedEDataVencimento(cobranca.ClienteId, cobranca.DataCobranca);
if (fatura != null)
fatura = ObterPorId(fatura.FaturaId.Value);
```

Dentro disso tenho algumas perguntas.

> Porque isso acontece?
>
> Como posso utilizar o E.F para trabalhar com o `Dapper` neste cenário?
>
> Qual a melhor forma de resolver este problema?

Comment: você poderia mostar o codigo do seu método `ObterPorClientedEDataVencimento`, acredito que o problema seja nele, pois provavelmente você pode ter desativado o tracker de entidade. Mostre também o código da entidade

Comment: @RodrigoK.B coloquei-as em um `Gist` pra não ficar muito extensa a pergunta.

Comment: @RodrigoK.B Como eu Habilito o Trakcer de Entidade?

Comment: Numca precisei de usar essa QueryMultiple, então n posso te dizer se está correto, mas analisando sua entidade vi que você colocou o id de fatura como anulável, acho que esse pode ser o problema. `public Guid? FaturaId { get; set; }`

Comment: Isso parece ser gambiarra. O que parece é que você tem uma entidade que já esta no contexto e esta tentando anexar-la novamente... mas com o que tem aqui não dar para saber.

Comment: Sobre a sua pergunta de habilitar o tracker, na verdade ele é default, porem quando fazemos uma query podemos desativar, caso essa query seja apenas para consulta, ou seja os objetos não serão modificados. Isso torna o EF mais ágil. talvez esse método de QueryMultiple, desative o tracker.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza Certo, por isso das perguntas no fim. estou tentando entender o problema, e buscando a melhor forma de resolver. Na verdade eu não tenho a entidade no contexto, por isso fazendo o `ObterPorId` eu trago para o contexto, e consigo alterá-lo. Seu comentário não agrega nada na pergunta, mas mesmo assim obrigado por ter lido, ao menos.

Comment: Uma dúvida, esse connection que você está utilizando, é criado pelo `var cn = Db.Database.Connection`, esse Db é o contexto do EF?

Comment: @RodrigoK.B Para consultas, utilizo somente o `Dapper`

Comment: Eu tinha que ter pensado nisso antes, o problema é que você está trazendo uma entidade fora do contexto do EF, assim ele não consegue fazer o tracker da entidade, é o tracker que define o estado da entidade. Talvez você conseguiria fazer apenas "Add", usando esse modelo que você nos apresentou.

Comment: @Connection ... você precisa entender o conceito do EF em relação a mapeamento de objeto ... veja o que seu erro diz.  failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value.... ou seja ela já esta no contexto... isso resolve seu problema https://stackoverflow.com/a/44836770/2740371

Comment: Perfeita a observação do @MarconcilioSouza, tanque que a mensagem que ocorreu, foi pelo fato de que como o EF não conseguiu identificar o estado da entidade, ele tentou fazer um "Add" da entidade, mesmo você setando o estado como "Modified".

Comment: @RodrigoK.B MarconcilioSouza Está na pergunta, que quando faço o ObterPeloId pelo o E.F, o problema não acontece. O problema é que as consultas não são feitas pelo E.F, mas sim pelo Dapper, o que estou buscando é uma forma de resolver fazendo a consulta pelo Dapper.

Comment: Mas o ObterPorId, você está usando o Dapper também, na pergunta você disse que usou o EF para faze-lo. Se puder publicar a função.

Comment: @RodrigoK.B Esse ObterPorId que fiz é somente um teste buscando identificar o problema. E ele é feito com utilizando o E.F

Comment: Então, quando você faz isso utilizando o EF, o traker da entidade está acontecendo, pois a entidade está no contexto, por isso que funcionou. Mesmo que o Id veja de uma consulta Dapper. Resumindo, acho impossível que uma entidade retornada fora do contexto do EF, seja possível fazer o que você quer.

Answer (score 1):

O Seu problema é que a consulta Dapper, está fora do contexto do EF, logo você não consegue modificar a entidade.

O erro ocorreu, pois ao tentar setar o estado da entidade como Modiffied, no Contexto do EF, pelo fato da entidade vir do Dapper, o EF quer adicionar a sua entidade no banco de dados. Então pelo fato do ID já existir, o EF te retorna este erro apresentado em sua pergunta.

Vejo que você tem duas saídas.

1. Mude a sua consulta para o EF, utilizando link, basicamente assim.

   `SeuContexto.Set(Fatura).Where(sua consulta aqui);`

Assim todas as entidades retornadas neste consulta, estarão no contexto do EF, assim você pode aplicar CRUD sem dificuldade.

2. Se você tiver que manter sua consulta Dapper, toda vez que precisar modificar este entidade, deverá fazer uma consulta pelo ID no EF, para que esta entidade esteja no contexto.